# What is the most "logical" route generating site (for Europe by car)?

Tags: cartography, routing

What is the most logical route generating site do you think is out there? By logical I mean optimizing the driving time between two points.  (Not always is the fastest way to proceed found along the shortest routes, making use of main-ways and highways when needed.)

I tried Google Maps. It seems to make use of highways a lot. Bing Maps, Mapquest, and Map24 all have different calculation methods but they seem to not use highways as much as Google Maps. I mentioned "for Europe by car" because I would like to take a trip from *københavn(denmark)* to *tekirdağ(turkey)*.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "most logical."  Are you seeking to optimize driving time between two points?  Or perhaps to optimize something else, such as routes that favor non-highways?

Comment: @whuber: yes, i am seeking to optimize the driving time between 2 points. for example, from A to B might there be a shorter road, but with lots of turns and narrow; whereas there might be a longer road from A to B but wider and allowing to drive faster.

Comment: Well, Google appears to [optimize driving time](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=k%C3%B8benhavn+%28denmark%29+to+tekirda%C4%9F+%28turkey%29) by default.  Google takes you through Berlin and directs you about 100 km east of Beograd, but otherwise looks the same as Michelin: the two solutions must therefore be very close in total estimated time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Via Michelin](http://www.viamichelin.com/web/Routes)

```
Total Costs from københavn(denmark) to tekirdağ(turkey) (based on default values)
    252.61 EUR
    Toll 0.00 EUR | Petrol 223.22 EUR | Road tax 29.39 EUR
Time
    27h19 which 17h10 on motorways
Distance
    2500 km which 1900 km on motorways
```

[image]

You can custom your route in fine detail - by  type of car - engine size etc:

Routing options:

**Michelin recommended** [The route deemed to be the safest and simplest with minimal scope for error along the way. The default recommended route from Michelin.]

**Quickest** [The route likely to offer the shortest journey time to the chosen destination, favouring main roads and, in particular, motorways.]

**Shortest** [The route offering the shortest distance to a destination via the most accessible roads. Journey times for this option will tend to be longer.]

**Sightseeing** [The route option for scenic roads that may have a touristic interest.]

**Economical** [The most fuel-efficient route that also avoids toll roads.]

Comment: thanks, (well at least on map) viamichelin generates a "better" route. for example going over serbia and not taking the road to stara zagora (instad goes over plovdiv)